# how to stop debug information when using oracle functions and NoSQLCS

Tags: oracle-nosql

How to avoid this DEBUG information when running Functions and python connected to a NoSQL table in OCI

> "01F4J52HHK1BT062RZJ00065AZ - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG XXXXXXXXXXX"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a separate logger for urllib3 or alternatively you could set your main logger level to something lower than debug

```
urllib3_logger = logging.getLogger('urllib3')
urllib3_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

or

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Comment: I tested using `logger = logging.getLogger() logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)` and it is working